# Split Text with 2 class in spans

Tags: javascript

I have this code to split my text in different spans and that works perfectly.

But I have 2x texts with 2x classes:

```
<p class="MyClass1">FIRST TEXT</p>
<p class="MyClass2">SEC TEXT</p>
```

code:

```
const p = document.querySelector(".MyClass1";
let words = p.textContent.split(" ");
words = words.map((word) => {
    let letters = word.split("");
    letters = letters.map(
        (letter) => `<span class="word_inner">${letter}</span>`
    );
    return letters.join("");
});
words = words.map((word) => `<span class="word">${word}</span>`);
p.innerHTML = words.join(" ");
```

How can I add a second .class in this code?

Comment: Turn it into a function and call it with your class-name

Comment: If you want to improve your questions in the future you can turn them into a runnable snippet :) Also avoid using innerHTML and look into [Create Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [Class List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) DOM functions.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `function`. Makes code reusable.

```js
function createSpans(myClass) {
    const p = document.querySelector(myClass);
    let words = p.textContent.split(" ");
    words = words.map((word) => {
        let letters = word.split("");
        letters = letters.map(
            (letter) => `<span class="word_inner">${letter}</span>`
        );
        return letters.join("");
    });
    words = words.map((word) => `<span class="word">${word}</span>`);
    p.innerHTML = words.join(" ");
}

createSpans(".MyClass1");
createSpans(".MyClass2");
```

```html
<p class="MyClass1">FIRST TEXT</p>
<p class="MyClass2">SEC TEXT</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! Why didn't I think of that myself. :-/